# Android AdView: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0xb6fc346e in tid 2826 (AdWorker #3)

Tags: android, admob, fault, adview

This error 
`libc : Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0xb6fc346e in tid 2826 (AdWorker #3)`
happened to pop up and I had no idea how to fix it as there was no stack trace. I am using the Genymotion emulator and it only shows up on Lollipop.

It is somehow connected to my Adview because when I comment `loadAd()` out error goes away.

```
avHomeAd = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.avHomeAd);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
//avHomeAd.loadAd(adRequest); <--commenting this out fixes it, but then I get no ads :(
```

How to fix?

Comment: Post code. Post Exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies within the permissions!
I commented out the `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission and it's not showing up anymore. Google AdMob docs says it's optional anyways.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!--This crashes app on Genymotion lollipop emulator when combined with AdView.
It is optional for adView says google docs, ignore the error msg thrown in logcat
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>-->
```

The downside is that sometimes the ads don't show up in the emulator, but it shows up on my real device (kitkat). I still don't know if including the permission will crash a real Lollipop device as I don't have one on hand! Maybe someone can chime in.

Your app might now throw this error (doesn't crash app) below and was the only reason I added the permission in the first place! But since it is optional and crashes the lollipop emulator, I'll just ignore it.

`E/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Error on GAThread: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10059 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.`

Comment: I don't even have this permission and it crashes on Lollipop emulator wtih: `A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0xf724224a in tid 3687 (AdWorker(Defaul)`